# Why do you not adjust standard errors at the individual level when autocorrelation is given?

Tags: clustering, autocorrelation, standard-error, random-effects-model, fixed-effects-model

I'm currently writing my bachelor thesis in behavioral economics and lately, I've been stuck with the following two sentences from Bellemare and Shearer (2009):

> Reported standard errors are corrected for clustering due to the presence of $\lambda_t$ and for arbitrary forms of heteroscedasticity in $\varepsilon_{it}$ (see Cameron and Trivedi, 2005, for details). We do not adjust the standard errors for clustering at the individual level since we include individual-specific effects which allow for autocorrelation of the composite error term. Below, we will consider autocorrelation in $\varepsilon_{it}$ and $\lambda_t$.

I completely understand why you have to adjust the standard errors in the first place, but what I don't get is why they are not adjusted at the individual level and why autocorrelation helps to avoid any biases in the outcome.